# Django - Can't import other app's model from same directory

Tags: python, django, model

I've got a problem with importing model from another app for Foreign key.
I tried two ways to use field from other model:

1. Import it as a string, it doesn't provide any errors before migrating model:

   from_city = models.ForeignKey(**'cities.City'**, blank=True,
   null=True,
   related_name='from_city_set',
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)

It provides an error when i'm trying to use "makekigrations" or "migrate" command

2. Import it as python object, but there is a strange moment. It tries to import 'city' app from src folder like that:

   from src.cities.models import City

   from_city = models.ForeignKey(**City**, blank=True,
   null=True,
   related_name='from_city_set',
   on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )

Both variants provides the same traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\TrainProject\src\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\TrainProject\src\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 196, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 361, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 329, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 89, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 724, in state_forwards
    state.alter_model_options(
  File "C:\TrainProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 182, in alter_model_options
    model_state = self.models[app_label, model_name]
KeyError: ('cities', 'city')
```

How can i solve it? 'train' app folder in the same place as 'cities' app.

UPD
Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'cities',
'trains',]
```

Models (cities/models and trains/models):

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='Название города')
```

---

```
class Train(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                        verbose_name='Название поезда')
travel_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Время в пути')
from_city = models.ForeignKey('cities.City', related_name='from_city_set',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE
                              )
to_city = models.ForeignKey('cities.City', related_name='to_city_set',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE
                            )
```

Comment: Share your `INSTALLED_APPS` and your `models.py` files

Comment: Added what you asked for at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I've solved this problem:

1. Delete your DB file
2. Delete everything from migrations folder in each app except file '**init**.py'
3. Run cmd 'python manage.py makemigrations' and 'python manage.py migrate'
4. Problem solved!

UPD

It doesn't matter how you import another model to ForeingKey field, it can be a python string or a python object (of course after you imported this model):

```
from_city = models.ForeignKey('cities.City', related_name='from_city_set',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE
                              )
_______________________________________________________________________

from city.models import City

from_city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='from_city_set',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE
                                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

*trains/models.py* should be like this:

```
from src.cities import models as city_md

class Train(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                        verbose_name='Название поезда')
travel_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Время в пути')
from_city = models.ForeignKey(city_md.City, related_name='from_city_set',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE
                              )
to_city = models.ForeignKey(city_md.City, related_name='to_city_set',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE
                            )
```

Comment: There is a problem - https://imgur.com/C6InFZ2
If i'm trying to make migrations with "from src.cities.models import City":
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\TrainProject\src\trains\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.cities.models import City
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Comment: That's why I don't use PyCharm anymore :)

Comment: I don't understand aren't they on the same directory? (cities and trains)

Comment: Of course in the same, maybe there is an extra folder (src folder inside project folder, but i guider told that this practice is common) - https://imgur.com/xi6gxlq